# XML parse error

Tags: php, xml

I have a **Valid** XML.

It asked me to treat the entire metadata record as the value of metadata element "dataxml", with newlines (and percent signs) indicated by percent signs (i.e. “percent-escaped”)

so i have done the following

Note: It asked me percent only the following : \n,\r, : and % so i only str_replaced those

```
$input .= 'dataxml: ' . str_replace(array(chr(hexdec('3A')),chr(hexdec('25')),chr(hexdec('0A')),chr(hexdec('0D'))),array('%3A', '%25', '%0A', '%0D'), $xmlfile) . "\n";
```

But it pops out the following error:

```
400 error:'dataxml': XML parse error: xmlns: URI http%253A//dataxml.org/schema/kernel-2.1 is not absolute
```

Can any one point out what i have done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colon in `http://` is being replaced twice: first the colon is replaced by `%3A` then the percent in that replacement is being replaced by `%25`.

You can use the function [`strtr()`](http://php.net/strtr) to avoid replacing already replaced parts of the string.

For example,

```
$input  .= 'dataxml: ' . strtr($xmlfile, array(":" => "%3A", "%" => "%25", "\n" => "%0A", "\r" => "%0D")) . "\n";
```

Comment: Is there a way that i can incorporate strtr() to the $input??

Comment: Sure, just like in your example.

Comment: I mean how can i add strtr() to the above line??

Comment: I've edited it to look like your example.